# How to create a queue of alert messages in Vue.js/Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have written some code that requires some amendments to cater for multiple alerts. It should also be able to accept a timeout duration so by default it needs to be 5000 but you should be able to override this property. Please could someone help me with this as I'm not sure how to go about it from this point.

`~/store/toast-messages.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
 color: '',
 message: '',
 type: ''
})

export const mutations = {
 showToast (state, payload) {
   state.color = payload.color
   state.message = payload.message
   state.type = payload.type
 }
}
```

`~/plugins/toasts.js`

```js
export default ({ store }, inject) => {
 inject('toasts', {
  showToast ({ color = '', message = '', type = '' }) {
    store.commit('toast-messages/showToast', { color, message, type })
  }
 })
}
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/toasts.js'
  ],
  ...
}
```

`~components/toasts/Toasts.vue`

```html
<template>
  <v-alert
    v-model="show"
    transition="slide-y-transition"
    :color="color"
    :type="type"
    dense
    prominent>
      {{ message }}
    </v-alert>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Toasts',
    data: () => {
      return {
        show: false,
        color: '',
        message: '',
        type: 'error',
    }
  },
  watch: {
    show (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.hideToast()
      }
    },
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
      if (mutation.type === 'toast-messages/showToast') {
        this.color = state['toast-messages'].color
        this.message = state['toast-messages'].message
        this.type = state['toast-messages'].type
        this.show = true
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    hideToast () {
      window.setInterval(() => {
      this.show = false
    }, 3000)
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

Called like this from anywhere in the app

```js
this.$toasts.showToast({
  color: 'red',
  type: 'error',
  message: err.message,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent component [Vue-SNotify](https://github.com/artemsky/vue-snotify) - example [here](https://artemsky.github.io/vue-snotify/).